# Tesla AC motor: operational question with field direction

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, induction-motor, electromagnetic

I have a question on the direction of the magnetic field for each of the four windings of the pictured AC motor. I ask because the wires are not clearly labeled as to direction of each winding, in which the current direction would change the magnetic field.

[image]

It seems there are two configurations for the wiring.  For each configuration, the direction of the magnetic field for opposite windings is either the same or opposing. If the field is opposing it seems some type of circular push occurs. If the field is the same the motor acts like a stepper.

**Is this understanding correct? If it is, what is the standard configuration for such a motor? If incorrect, guidance is appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes except the rotor is different and only 2 poles /rev. C=C and opposite to C'=C' so commutator may also invert to keep attraction force in the same direction